# ssh-copy-id no identities found error

Tags: unix, ssh, ssh-keys

I have few client systems where I need to push the ssh key and login from my server without authentication prompts.

First, on the server,  I created ssh key as below which was successful

```
]# ssh-keygen -t rsa -N "" -f my.key
```

Second, tried copying the pub key but fails with no identity error. Am i doing a wrong step here?

```
]# ssh-copy-id my.key.pub 10.10.1.1
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: ERROR: No identities found
```

Comment: did you confirm that `my.key` is there with `ls -l my.key`? Is there a step you're not showing us that did a `cd`? Probably not, but just asking as your "2nd set of eyes" ;-). Good luck.

Answer (score 88):

You need to use the `-i` flag:

```
ssh-copy-id -i my.key.pub 10.10.1.1
```

From the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-copy-id):

> If the -i option is given then the identity file (defaults to ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub) is used, regardless of whether there are any keys in your ssh-agent. Otherwise, if this: ssh-add -L provides any output, it uses that in preference to the identity file

Comment: I tried with -i option and pushed the key successfully to target. Also verified authorized_keys file and the key appears to be there.. Then after i tried ssh root@10.10.1.1 but still then prompts for a password.. is there anything more required here. ?                                                                                            ssh-copy-id -i my.key.pub 10.10.1.1
Now try logging into the machine, with "ssh '10.10.1.1'", and check in:

  .ssh/authorized_keys

to make sure we haven't added extra keys that you weren't expecting.

~]# ssh root@10.10.1.1
root@10.10.1.1's password:

Comment: ssh by default looks in `~/.ssh` for your keys etc. Since your `my.key` files appear to be in another directory, try `ssh -i /location/of/my.key 10.10.1.1` (or consider moving your my.key files into `~/.ssh`)

Comment: "Then after i tried ssh root@10.10.1.1 but still then prompts for a password."

The first ssh-copy-id command is for logging in as you, not as root.  You need another ssh-copy-id command for logging in as root.  ssh-copy-id -i root@my.key.pub 10.10.1.1

Answer (score 86):

Generating ssh keys on the client solved it for me

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

Comment: I'd say this is the one that works for the usual case (making an SSH key in the default location)

Comment: Just `ssh-keygen` worked for me. No need to specify `-t rsa` .

Comment: If you get the `ssh-copy-id` on a new Linux machine, it's always good to check if `ssh-keygen` has been run.

Answer (score 34):

Run following command

```
# ssh-add
```

If it gives following error:
 Could not open a connection to your authentication agent

To remove this error, Run following command:

```
# eval `ssh-agent`
```

Comment: After executing eval `ssh-agent` execute ssh-add and then ssh-copy-id and everything should work correctly.

Comment: Thank you! I've been trying to figure out what wasn't working, but this solved it

Comment: the original error ```/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: ERROR: No identities found``` still persists even after running above commands

Comment: Didn't help for me either

Answer (score 26):

The simplest way is to:

```
ssh-keygen
[enter]
[enter]
[enter]

cd ~/.ssh
ssh-copy-id -i id_rsa.pub USERNAME@SERVERTARGET
```

Att:

Its very very simple.

In manual of "ss-keygen" explains:

"DESCRIPTION
     ssh-keygen generates, manages and converts authentication keys for ssh(1).  ssh-keygen can create RSA keys for use by SSH protocol version 1 and
     DSA, ECDSA or RSA keys for use by SSH protocol version 2.  The type of key to be generated is specified with the -t option.  **If invoked without
     any arguments, ssh-keygen will generate an RSA key for use in SSH protocol 2 connections.**"

Comment: Thanks. This worked. I didn't have to generate a key as I already had one. It was changing to the .ssh directory and using  that command that did it.

Answer (score 10):

The ssh-copy-id is not able to locate the id_rsa.pub file that is generated by ssh-keygen in your system, Use the following command to complete:

1. find the path of the .pub file:
   `locate *.pub`
2. copy the path (ex: /home/user_name/.ssh/id_rsa.pub) and run the following command:
   `ssh-copy-id -i /home/user_name/.ssh/id_rsa.pub hostname`

Answer (score 9):

You need to specify the key by using -i option.

```
ssh-copy-id -i your_public_key user@host
```

Thanks.

Comment: This is the same answer as the one posted on [March 20,2014](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22532600/3276962).

Answer (score 7):

Old post but I came up with this problem today, ended up googling and had found myself here. I had figured it out on my own but thought I'd share my issue & solution in my case to help out anyone else who may have the same issue.

Issue:

```
[root@centos [username]]# ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

`Enter file in which to save the key (/root/.ssh/id_rsa):`I HAD JUST HIT ENTER

```
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: ERROR: No identities found
```

Solution:

```
Enter file in which to save the key (/root/.ssh/id_rsa): **/home/[username]/id_rsa**
```

Be sure if you are doing this as root you are coping the key into the user directory you wish to login with. NOT the root user directory.

I was sshing into the machine when performing this operation, so I guess ssh-copy-id just point to the dir you are logged in as by default.

Hope this helps anyone.

Answer (score 6):

came up across this one, on an **existing** account with private key I copied manually from elsewhere. so the error is because the **public** key is missing

so simply generate one from private

```
 ssh-keygen -y -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa > ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Answer (score 4):

Actually issues in one of Ubuntu machine is ssh-keygen command was not run properly. I tried running again and navigated into /home/user1/.ssh and able to see id_rsa and id_rsa.pub keys. then tried command ssh-copy-id   and it was working fine.

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, the -i option was a red herring for me.  ssh-copy-id will use ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub by default.

What was keeping it from working for me was the permissions on the ~ directory, the ~/.ssh directory, and the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file on the remote computer.

All three need to be set with `chmod 755 ~ ~/.ssh ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`, then `ssh-copy-id your-remote-server.com` will work.

Comment: according to the [documentation](https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/droplets/resources/troubleshooting-ssh/authentication/#fixing-key-permissions-and-ownership), permissions should be `700` and `600` accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. The problem was my `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` file being *empty*. I overwritten it somehow while messing around with my ssh config. The problem is solved after correcting the file.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced this problem today while setting up ssh between name node and data node in fully distributed mode between two VMs in CentOS.

The problem was faced because I ran the below command from data node instead of name node
ssh-copy-id -i /home/hduser/.ssh/id_ras.pub hduser@HadoopBox2

Since the public key file did not exist in data node it threw the error.

Comment: My issue was that I was running the command from `root` (via sudo, as I wanted `root` to login without password to a remote server). Ubuntu apparently was looking the key in the user's home which was missing the `.ssh` directory. It seems that `ssh-copy-id` uses that `.ssh` directory temporally in order to upload the key. Thanks to `-i /home/.../id_rsa.pub` argument, I was able to notice that. After creating that directory, I was able to upload the key and to login from `root` successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Use simple
`ssh-keyscan hostname` to find if key(s) exists on both sites:

```
ssh-keyscan rc1.localdomain
[or@rc2 ~]$ ssh-keyscan rc1
# rc1 SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
rc1 ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABI.......==

ssh-keyscan rc2.localdomain
[or@rc2 ~]$ ssh-keyscan rc2
# rac2 SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
rac2 ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAys7kG6pNiC.......==
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ssh-keygen
```

then

```
sudo service ssh restart
```

after this, you should be able to use ssh-copy-id without having to provide any additional commands

Answer (score 0):

Might sound stupid, but for some reason the file I needed to copy did not have the correct name. It was called `id_rsa.pu`.
Be sure the file name is exactly `id_rsa.pub` or tell `ssh-copy-id` to pickup on a specific identity file with `ssh-copy-id -i path/to/identity_file.pub`

Answer (score 0):

```
ssh-keygen
ssh-copy-id root@127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Comment: Are you sure about the IP address you used? It doesn't match the one in the question.

Answer (score -3):

In my case it was the missing `.pub` extension of a key. I pasted it from clipboard and saved as `mykey`. The following command returned described error:

```
ssh-copy-id -i mykey localhost
```

After renaming it with `mv mykey mykey.pub`, works correctly.

```
ssh-copy-id -i mykey.pub localhost
```